# Explicit example of working with Lie derivative of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms, lie-derivative

I know the definition of a Lie derivative, but I'm having trouble applying that to a concrete example.

The Lie derivative on vector field $X$ and form $\omega$ is $$L_X\omega(p) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\phi_t^X)^*(\omega(\phi_t^X(p))) - \omega(p)}{t}$$

So, say I have the vector field $X = -x_2\partial_{x_1} + x_1\partial_{x_2}$, and 1-form $\omega = \frac{x_2dx_1 - x_1dx_2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ (all in $\mathbb{R}^2$), then what is $L_X\omega$, using the limit definition of Lie derivative?

Here, the integral curve of $X$ at a point $p = (p_1, p_2)$ is $(p_1\cos(t) - p_2\sin(t), p_2\cos(t) + p_1\sin(t)$.

---

I would appreciate it if you could walk me through how to find the Lie derivative, this is not a homework question, but an example that I came up with by picking out arbitrary values that I've came across on this topic. I can't guarantee that this will work, and please suggest an example for me if there is something more illustrative.

Comment: Using the definition directly is almost always the worst way of calculating things. Even for simple things like calculating the derivative of $f(x) = \sin(x^3)$, using the definition directly is always a nightmare. It is best to always use the basic theorems which enable more efficient computations (in the example for $f$ it is the chain rule, and knowledge of derivatives of "basic functions"). In your case, you should try to understand first what $L_X(dx_1)$ and $L_X(dx_2)$ are. Then, try to understand what $L_X(f\, dx_1)$ is. Then finally put all of that together for $L_X(\omega)$.

Comment: You'll want to learn about [Cartan's magic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product#Properties).

Comment: @JackLee I do, but I still think it's worthwhile to at least work through the basic definition once

Comment: If you want to do the calculation explicitly, did you consider writing things in polar coordinates? That's the first thing that jumped out at me when I looked at your question. You've already seen that the flow of $X$ gives you circles centered at the origin. Doesn't $\omega$ look a lot like $-d\theta$?